# Add events to Google calendar App in Android

Tags: android

By using JAVA to develop Android Application 
I need to add events to Google calendar App in Android, 
in my application i have task form contains information about Task that will be inserted by the user, and the end of the form there is (add button) that will inset the task directlly to Google calender . 
but the problem that I faced is, when the user click on add button, the application shows Google calender form, and i don't need this form, I want to add the task to the calendar directly, depending on the information provided by the my application user.

this is part of java code

```
     public void addCalendarEvent(){

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();    
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
        intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
        intent.putExtra("beginTime", cal.getTimeInMillis());
        intent.putExtra("allDay", true);
        intent.putExtra("rrule", "FREQ=YEARLY");
        intent.putExtra("endTime", cal.getTimeInMillis()+60*60*1000);
        intent.putExtra("title", "A Test Event from android app");
        intent.putExtra("description", "A Test Description from android app");
        intent.putExtra("eventLocation", "Geolocation");
        startActivity(intent);

      }
```

in Google calender, what is the different between event and task?!!!!
Waiting.

Comment: There is no such thing as "native android calendar".  Any device can use any calendar app they want.  Some devices won't use Google calendar at all.  Others may write their own app to access it.  Yet other devices may not have a calendar app at all.  Anything that depends on vnd.android.anything is fragile.  Since Calendar isn't a system service of any sort, there is no way to ensure this will work on all devices.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add something to the calendar without using android-calendar-gui you have to use the android calendar contentprovider at "content:com.android.calendar/..." and your app needs permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
```

The api is available since android 4.0 via class CalendarContract

For a working example see the sources of [birthday-adapter](https://github.com/dschuermann/birthday-adapter) which opens the contanc and inserts every contact-birthday found as a calendar-event